# replace some value in text line in c++

Tags: c++

Hi guys i use this code to find the line included  `seta r_fullscreen "0"` and if the value for this line is 0 return MessageBox but my question is if the value of `seta r_fullscreen`is "0" so how i can replace this value to "1" in this line ?

```
ifstream cfgm2("players\\config_m2.cfg",ios::in);
string cfgLine; 
    Process32First(proc_Snap , &pe32);
    do{     
        while (getline(cfgm2,cfgLine)) {
        if (string::npos != cfgLine.find("seta r_fullscreen")){
        if (cfgLine.at(19) == '0'){

        MessageBox(NULL,"run in full Screen mod.","ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

        ...
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `cfgLine.at(19) = '1'`

Comment: Where do you want to replace the '1'? In the string or in the .cfg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) to do this. After you have located the line containing the configuration specifier `seta r_fullscreen` you can do something like the following.

```
std::string::size_type pos = cfgLine.find("\"0\"");
if(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    cfgLine.replace(pos, 3, "\"1\"");
}
```

You should not assume that the configuration value `"0"` is at a specific offset as there may be additional spaces between `r_fullscreen` and `"0"`.

After seeing your additional comments you need to update the configuration file after the changes have been made. The changes you make to the string only apply to the copy in memory and are not automatically saved to the file. You will need to save each line after it has been loaded and changed and then save the updates out to the file.  You should also move the process of updating the config file outside of `do/while` loop.  If yo don't you will read/update the file for each process you check.

The example below should get you started.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


std::ifstream cfgm2("players\\config_m2.cfg", std::ios::in);
if(cfgm2.is_open())
{
    std::string cfgLine; 
    bool changed = false;
    std::vector<std::string> cfgContents;
    while (std::getline(cfgm2,cfgLine))
    {
        // Check if this is a line that can be changed
        if (std::string::npos != cfgLine.find("seta r_fullscreen"))
        {
            // Find the value we want to change
            std::string::size_type pos = cfgLine.find("\"0\"");
            if(pos != std::string::npos)
            {
                // We found it, not let's change it and set a flag indicating the
                // configuration needs to be saved back out.
                cfgLine.replace(pos, 3, "\"1\"");
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        // Save the line for later.
        cfgContents.push_back(cfgLine);
    }

    cfgm2.close();

    if(changed == true)
    {
        // In the real world this would be saved to a temporary and the
        // original replaced once saving has successfully completed. That
        // step is omitted for simplicity of example.
        std::ofstream outCfg("players\\config_m2.cfg", std::ios::out);
        if(outCfg.is_open())
        {
            // iterate through every line we have saved in the vector and save it
            for(auto it = cfgContents.begin();
                it != cfgContents.end();
                ++it)
            {
                outCfg << *it << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Rest of your code
Process32First(proc_Snap , &pe32);
do {
    // some loop doing something I don't even want to know about
} while ( /*...*/ );
```

Comment: all of this answers is perfect but i dont know why in my cfg file this value not changed to "1" ?!!  :|

Comment: Did you save the changes to the configuration file?

Comment: yes pleas see my full source in pastebin maybe its helpful thanks.  [link]http://pastebin.com/fqGWar0n

Comment: You are _not_ saving the changes to the configuration file. The changes you made to the string only apply to the copy in memory, not the actual part of the file.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include code to save the changes.

Comment: pleas explain, sorry i am beginner in c++ pls if possible complete my source.thanks

Comment: Dude!! Really? My answer provides _complete_ example code to load, change and update the configuration file. I've also included additional comments _and_ tested it. At this point I'm done. Please put forth some effort and try applying the provided solution before asking someone else to do all of your work.